# OAuth "Facebook Platform" "insufficient_scope" (#200)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The error I get as a response from the graph API, it's a HTTP 403 with the following message:

> OAuth "Facebook Platform" "insufficient_scope" "(#200) can only create
>   object types owned by calling application or global object types"

I have 3 **Facebook** apps

- Production (not approved yet)

and 2 tests apps based on **production**

- Development
- Staging

It's obvious the three of them have differents IDS, since Development and Staging are "tests apps" I can't create custom stories to replicate the ones that I have on "production".

The issue happens when I try to post a custom activity created in production from any of the test apps.

is there any way to solve this?

Comment: This is my problem as well, any luck solving it?

Comment: yes but I don't remember how I solved it, it was related to an option that I activated (some toggle to true) in some app setting, the best you can do is to capture your screen upload it as a video and post a bug in the developer facebook support, they'll give you the solution.